# Node app not connecting to heroku redis in production

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

My node app was connecting to heroku redis fine when in development on localhost. When I deployed (I use Heroku for deployment) my app no longer connects to Heroku Redis. My requests that use the redis client are just timing out. Here's my code that connects to Redis.

```
import Redis from "ioredis";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

export const client = new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL, {
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});
```

Then in my controllers I just import { client } from the above connection file. Does anyone know why connection doesn't work in deployment vs development?

Edit: The exact error I'm getting in my heroku logs is - [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Comment: Does `process.env.REDIS_URL` contain the value you expect it to?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with both the tls connection url (starts with rediss) and the non tls connection url. Both timeout in production but not development.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've tried with both..."? Are you _modifying_ `REDIS_URL`? You should let _Heroku_ set that value.

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular: "**Post the question and respond to feedback** After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!"